# Is every point in $A $ a limit point of $A$. ? Yes/No

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is the following statement is true/false ?

Let  $(X,d)$ be  a metric space. Let $A$  be   closed set in $X$. Every point  in $A $ is a  limit point of $A$.

My attempt :  I thinks this statement is true . Take $X = \mathbb{R}$  and $A =[0,1]$

Comment: One example doesn't prove the statement. Recall the equivalent definitions of closed sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A =\{0\} \cup [2,3]$ then $ 0 \in A$ but $0$ is not a limit point of $A$.